# find files without any extension

Tags: find

How do I find the files those do not have an extension? For e.g. in the following screen, I will like to return the file sconnect and not .xls

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12K Mar  7 19:29 ./Purchase_ORDER.xls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 176 Mar  7 19:29 ./sconnect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
# find -type f -not -name '*.*'
```

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You just do `find . \! -name '*.*'`

(add `-type f` if you need exactly files)